# Where did System.Reflection.MemberTypes go in DNX 5.0?

Tags: c#, reflection, dnx

.net 4.5 had it.
Where is it in DNXCore v5?

My specific error message is:
`DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name 'MemberTypes' does not exist in the current context.`

In previous .nets, it was an `Enum` on `System.Reflection` and would be the result of `obj.GetType().GetMember(memberName).MemberType` (Field, Property, etc)

---

**Edit**:

This is what I'm doing:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

    internal static object Send(object obj, string callableName, object[] parameters = null)
    {
        var info = InfoFor(obj, callableName);
        return ValueFor(obj, info);
    }
```

Where `InfoFor` returns either `MethodInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, or whatever else would match `callableName`

and ValueFor below (where MemberTypes is trying to be used)

```
  private static object ValueFor(object obj, dynamic member)
        {
            object value = null;

            if (member != null)
            {
                switch ((System.Reflection.MemberTypes)member.MemberType)
                {
                    case MemberTypes.Field:
                        value = ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(obj);
                        break;
                    case MemberTypes.Property:
                        value = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(obj, null);
                        break;
                   ...
```

Comment: Post your code so somebody can recommend a viable alternative.

Comment: Do a code search on http://github.com/dotnet/corefx, and check if it does exist.

Comment: I think this is actually a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4670

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like (at least for now) [this is the recommended way to achieve the same functionality.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4670#issuecomment-159665089)

```
FieldInfo field = member as FieldInfo;
if (field != null)
   return field.GetValue(obj);
PropertyInfo property member as PropertyInfo;
if (property != null)
   return property.GetValue(obj, null);
```